# Add '-' to a numeric input field

Tags: html, angularjs

I am developing a website that is a responsive website, but i got stuck a little with a mobile issue.
When there is an input field that is a 'number' on mobile devices it will pop up the numeric keyboard, but it appears that the 'native' Samsung numeric keyboards doesn't have the minus sign ('-') which is needed in the website, so I've added a button that will appear in mobile browsers and will add the minus sign, but now there is a new problem:

Because the input field is a 'number' i can't add the minus sign programmatically, here is what I've tried to do but it fails:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myNumber">
<button type="button" ng-click="myNumber = myNumber + '-'">Add Minus</button>
```

When the button is being pressed i am getting the error:

`Expected '-' to be a number`

It kinda make sense because it probably checks if it is a type of number (which is not) and throw this error, but if i will use a PC keyboard or a mobile numeric keyboard that has the minus sign it does accept it.

Is there a way to avoid this error somehow and do insert the minus sign into the input field?

## Edit

What i wanted is that it will be the same effect that you get when you have a pc keyboard it means that `-5645-56` is possible (because it does possible in an input field 'number') but i guess that even if it is possible it will be much harder to do, and there is not such a good reason for that so the approaches you suggested can work as well.

Thank you!

Comment: You are not adding a minus sign, you are creating a string that looks like this: `"5-"` (which is not `-5`). You can try to multiply it by `-1`.

Comment: If you have `myNumber` and run `myNumber + '-'`, you will get `3-`. Have you tried  `ng-click="myNumber = myNumber * -1"` or `ng-click="myNumber = -myNumber"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just do

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myNumber">
<button type="button" ng-click="myNumber = (myNumber > 0) ? -myNumber : myNumber">Add Minus</button>
```